# How to copy text from file on one server and append to file on another with ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to copy content from file on one linux server to file on another linux server with ssh. I am on third machine and I am using one same public key on both linux servers to connect without password.

I know that is something like this:

```
ssh -A user1@server1 "cat fajl1..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ssh` in a pipe.  I will assume you have machines server1, server2 and server3.  If you are on server 2, it would look like this:

```
ssh -A user1@server1 "cat server1file" | ssh user1@server3 "cat >> server3file"
```

The first `ssh` command starts a pipeline over the network that the second ssh command picks up and appends to the destination file on its file system.

Comment: Please write whole command, I dont get where to put "".

Comment: My example was too simple and did not address your 3 machine problem.  I have adjusted the answer.

Comment: Works! That is right command, I put pipe under " " each time and that messed up everything.Thanks!